# Android: Cant Read File

Tags: java, android, permissions, file-permissions

Here is my code:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Uri selectedimg) throws IOException {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    Log.d("selectedimg"," selectedimg = " + selectedimg);
    fileDescriptor =
            getActivity().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedimg, "r");

    Bitmap original
            = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
    return original;
}
```

I safe the bitmap after i launch the camera intent with the result image.
Than i try to read the image into a bitmap.
The image is there and not damaged.

I get the error:

```
> 08-10 15:26:58.578 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
08-10 15:26:58.578 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:270)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:970)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:898)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment$override.getBitmap(PickImageFragment.java:159)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment$override.onActivityResult(PickImageFragment.java:130)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment$override.access$dispatch(PickImageFragment.java)
08-10 15:26:58.579 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.onActivityResult(PickImageFragment.java:0)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6537)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3772)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3819)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-10 15:26:58.580 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
08-10 15:26:58.581 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
08-10 15:26:58.581 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 15:26:58.581 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-10 15:26:58.581 26729-26729/com.ebed.scannerod W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It says that i dont have the permission to do this but i declaired all Premissions i need (Camera Read and Write) in the Manifest file. I run it API 24.

I dont know what i could do to solve this problem.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: check if `Uri selectedimg` is not null

Comment: i am also facing this problem

Comment: You would need to provide runtime permission starting 6.0 please have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i check every time the uri isnt null.

Comment: at times it has nothing to do with manifest-permissions, but the directory and its contents are locked from RW. What does `file.canWrite()` tell you?